# How to discard load from cache in composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I want to install a package from source (ignoring load from cache).
I don't want clear the composer cache, I want to know is there any command or parameter to discarding the load from cache in composer?

Comment: Do you want to selectively clear items from the cache or always load selected dependencies from source? Those are two different operations with similar outcomes.

Comment: I need to load some packages from the source not all packages

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does composer.json record --prefer-source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43313173/how-does-composer-json-record-prefer-source)

Answer (score 5):

use

```
composer clearcache
```

that will do the job

also

```
composer update --no-cache
```

Comment: The "--no-cache" option does not exist

Comment: @AchrafJEDAY please check here https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#global-options